The relation between aerodynamic center and lift
On the internet, I found two separate definitions for the aerodynamic center. One was "the point where pitching moment is constant regardless of angle of attack" and the other was "the application point of lift". I tried to figure out how the second definition can be made from the first and I thought it was because since pitching moment is force multiplied by distance, if the AC is the point of application of lift, it wouldn't change from AoA. However, I still don't understand a few things.

Since lift is caused by airfoil shape, doesn't a change in AoA cause both the main wing and tail wings' lift to change? Or do both forces change by the same amount so that the application point of lift stays constant?
Even if the two lift forces change by the same amount, doesn't gravity contribute to pitching moment? I'm almost sure gravity doesn't change from AoA.
Or should I understand the first definition as the lift on individual mass points not changing from the AoA?

TLDR, how does the pitching moment not changing from AoA at the AC make it a point of application of lift?
P.S. Please explain any new technical terms and correct me if I'm wrong about anything, as I'm a middle schooler who's new to this field.

That may help: What is the difference between centre of pressure, aerodynamic centre and neutral point?


"the point where pitching moment is constant regardless of angle of attack"

is called the neutral point or the aerodynamic center.

"the application point of lift"

is indeed the center of lift or center of pressure.
Please do not believe outright what you read on the interwebs. So many people get the details wrong because they simply copy from others. Instead, try to comprehend what happens in detail and ask yourself every time "can that be right?". You'll be surprised how often the answer is "no".
Please follow the links for the requested explanation of the terms. They can be applied to a single airfoil (2D flow), a whole wing or the complete airplane (both 3D flow), each time with different meanings, as @sophit correctly mentions.

You'd better specify that the terminology can be applied to the whole aircraft, only to the the wing or to the airfoil. With different meanings.

@sophit Good idea to do it already here, even though the linked answers do it, too.
